# Can't find cause of HY093 Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match num ber of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have a page with 8 checkboxes on it. Depending on how many checkboxes are checked, an sql statement is created. E.g.: if two checkboxes are checked, an array of 24 names (out of a maximum of 32) has to update a table. When 3 are checked, 20 rows need to be updated.

In my PHP logic I check how many checkboxes are checked, let's say 3 are checked. I then create the PDO update statement using placeholders, like so :

```
.
.
case 20:
  $sstring = "left1 = :n1, left2 = :n2, left3 = :n3, left4 = :n4,
              left5 = :n5, left6 = :n6, left7 = :n7, left8 = :n8,
              left9 = :n9, left10 = :n10, left11 = :n11, left12 = :n12,
              left13 = :n13, left14 = :n14, left15 = :n15, left16 = :n16,
              left17 = :n17, left18 = :n18, left19 = :n19, left20 = :n20";
  break;
.
.
```

Then, I create the sql statement, like this (remember: PHP):

```
$sql = "UPDATE drawleft SET " . $sstring . " WHERE year = :year";
```

Next, I do the prepare :

```
$stmt1=$db->prepare($sql);
```

And finally, I complete the update sending the data :

```
.
.
case 20:
  $qstring = "':year' => $year, ':n1' => $nm_array[0], ':n2' => $nm_array[1],
              ':n3' => $nm_array[2], ':n4' => $nm_array[3], ':n5' => $nm_array[4],
              ':n6' => $nm_array[5], ':n7' => $nm_array[6], ':n8' => $nm_array[7],
              ':n9' => $nm_array[8], ':n10' => $nm_array[9], ':n11' => $nm_array[10],
              ':n12' => $nm_array[11], ':n13' => $nm_array[12], ':n14' => $nm_array[13],
              ':n15' => $nm_array[14], ':n16' => $nm_array[15], ':n17' => $nm_array[16],
              ':n18' => $nm_array[17], ':n19' => $nm_array[18], ':n20' => $nm_array[19]";
break;
.
.
```

Now when I do `$result = $stmt1->execute(array($qstring));`, I get an error 500 back, and I see in the apache error_log the HY093 error: `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

When I do the following (without `array`) :

```
$result = $stmt1->execute($qstring);
```

I get a PDO warning : `PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given`

Comparing the number of placeholders against the number of values submitted during the execute(), I can only conclude that they are the same.

So, please, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here ? (apart from not coding too well...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$qstring = "':year' => $year, ':n1' => $nm_array[0], ':n2' => $nm_array[1],
              ':n3' => $nm_array[2], ':n4' => $nm_array[3], ':n5' => $nm_array[4],
              ':n6' => $nm_array[5], ':n7' => $nm_array[6], ':n8' => $nm_array[7],
              ':n9' => $nm_array[8], ':n10' => $nm_array[9], ':n11' => $nm_array[10],
              ':n12' => $nm_array[11], ':n13' => $nm_array[12], ':n14' => $nm_array[13],
              ':n15' => $nm_array[14], ':n16' => $nm_array[15], ':n17' => $nm_array[16],
              ':n18' => $nm_array[17], ':n19' => $nm_array[18], ':n20' => $nm_array[19]";
```

needs to be

```
$qstring = array(':year' => $year, ':n1' => $nm_array[0], ':n2' => $nm_array[1],
              ':n3' => $nm_array[2], ':n4' => $nm_array[3], ':n5' => $nm_array[4],
              ':n6' => $nm_array[5], ':n7' => $nm_array[6], ':n8' => $nm_array[7],
              ':n9' => $nm_array[8], ':n10' => $nm_array[9], ':n11' => $nm_array[10],
              ':n12' => $nm_array[11], ':n13' => $nm_array[12], ':n14' => $nm_array[13],
              ':n15' => $nm_array[14], ':n16' => $nm_array[15], ':n17' => $nm_array[16],
              ':n18' => $nm_array[17], ':n19' => $nm_array[18], ':n20' => $nm_array[19]);
```

Comment: Thank you ! That was it. Learning all the time !

Answer (score 0):

I can't make any plausible explanation why you're using named placeholders here.

With positional placeholders you will need no such a monster array at all. As well as a monster switch case probably.

given your $sstring is like

```
foo=?, bar=?, baz=? ...
```

you can do something as simple as

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE drawleft SET $sstring WHERE year = ?");
$nm_array[] = $year;
$stmt->execute($nm_array);
```

This. Is. All.

Only make sure that field names in the $sstring are not [vulnerable to SQL injection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example).

Answer (score -1):

Try a more readable version:

instead of:

```
$sql = "UPDATE drawleft SET " . $sstring . " WHERE year = :year";
```

use:

```
$sql = "UPDATE drawleft SET left=:n1, left2=:n2 WHERE year = :year";
$prepared = $stmt1->prepare($sql);
$result = $prepared->execute(array(':n1' => $nm_array[0], ':n2' => $nm_array[1], ':year' => $your_year));
```

An alternative way:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE drawleft SET left=:n1, left2=:n2 WHERE year = :year");
$stmt->bindParam(':n1', $nm_array[0]);
$stmt->bindParam(':n2', $nm_array[1]);
$stmt->bindParam(':year', $your_year);
$result = $prepared->execute();
```

Comment: Dan, I agree that this is much more readable, but since the number of fields that will be updated is dependant on the number of checkboxes checked, I need to construct the SET part of $sql, as well as the execute(array( part accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @notaverygoodprogrammer Ok i understand, maby it's time to move to the right approach for the future, an ORM. There are a lot of options there i personally used Doctrine but there are many. You could the just use the DBAL not the whole ORM first.